# Escape character in JPQL

Tags: jpa, jpql

In JPQL what is escape character we can use to escape characters such as "'"?

Ex : I am doing something like

`...where person.name='Andy'`

Here it is working fine

but when the person's name is Andy's then the `where` clause becomes like

`...where person.name='Andy's'`

and it returns an error saying

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It cannot figure out where string literal ends. Solution is nicely told in specification:

> A string literal that includes a single quote is represented by two
> single quotes—for example: ‘literal’’s’.

In your case means:

```
...where person.name='Andy''s'
```

Answer (score 5):

Below is the sample code for executing query using named parameter.

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.name LIKE :name" ); 

query.setParameter("name", personName);
```

Here, you can pass string to `personName` which may contain special character like "Andy's".

Also, it looks much clean & doesn't require to check parameter before query execution & altering the search string.